# How to update properties of child actors from supervisor?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm using akka to create a supervisor :

```
mySupervisor = actorSys.actorOf(Props.create(MyActor.class, MyProperties()));

class MyProperties(){

    String param1;
    String param2;

    //param1 & param2 are set in a configuration file
}
```

Since creating a supervisor from the ActorSystem is expensive I'm just doing this once. I'm using the class MyProperties in order to
access various parameters that are required within the actor. I do not want to add the logic for setting the propertes to the actor itself so the actor
has little work to perform as possible and the usually these peoperties will not change. But when the properties do change how can I update
the child actors of the supervisor ? I do not think I can change the state of mySupervisor (since immutable) so does this mean I will need to create a new supervisor with the
new properties configuration ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never never ever ever ever ever change the state of an actor with anything ***except*** a message sent to that actor.

If you need to change the properties of a child actor, you can:

- Kill the actor and create a replacement with the new properties
- Send a message to the actor with new properties

In addition, messages sent to an actor should be immutable (`final String param1`).  If you need to access an actor's internal state, you should send that actor a message asking for it and then have the actor reply to that request with whatever (immutable) state is needed.

Comment: Can you expand on "Send a message to the actor with new properties" Can this message be of any type. e.g MyProperties ? If an actor is being sent a message with the properties does that not mean that it's state needs to be updated on order to use the new properties or is just new actors that are created from the supervisor utilize the new properties and existing actors cannot be updated ?

Comment: It's up to you.  You could just send a `MyProperties` instance to the  actor.  If you want to just change an existing actor's state, do that.  An actor's *internal* state is entirely up to you and can safely be modified so long as such modifications are only done using message passing.